# How to use function wrapper in mustache.php?

Tags: php, mustache, mustache.php

I'm starting to work with Mustache on PHP and I don't manage to make wrapper functions to work as debt.

I have this template

```
{{#skill_level}}
  <span class="stars">
    {{#stars}}
      {{skill_level}} 
    {{/stars}}                        
  </span>
{{/skill_level}}
```

And I have this data

```
$data = new StdClass;
$data->skill_level = 3;
$data->stars = function($level) {
  $aux = "";
  $l = intVal($level);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    $aux .= "+";
  }
  for ($i = $l; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $aux .= ".";
  }
  return $aux;
};
```

I render `m.render($tenplate, $data);` and I would like to obtain something like:

```
<span class="stars">
    +++..                        
</span>
```

But it doesn't work.

I get

```
<span class="stars">
    .....                        
</span>
```

Because `Mustache` is passing `"{{skill_level}}"`to my function instead of value `3`.

Furthermore if I change the template a put backspaces in the mustache labels:

```
{{ #skill_level }}
  <span class="stars">
    {{ #stars }}
      {{ skill_level }} 
    {{ /stars }}                        
  </span>
{{ /skill_level }}
```

Then `{{ skill_level }}` is processed but it isn't sent to `{{ #starts }}`, the render obtained is

```
<span class="stars">
    3                        
</span>
```

So, does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? How should I wrote the template to make it works? Any advice or experience are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the answer in the [wiki of the project](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags#lambdas)

> The text passed is the literal block, unrendered.

But it provides a `Mustache_LambdaHelper` that can be used to render the text passed.

So I have to add this to my *lambda* function:

```
$data->stars = function($label, Mustache_LambdaHelper $helper) {     
  $aux = "";
  $level = $helper->render($label);
  $l = intVal($level);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    $aux .= "+";
  }
  for ($i = $l; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $aux .= ".";
  }
  return $aux;
};
```

And that's all it's needed to make it works. Thanks to all readers!

Comment: I'd prolly code your lambda something like this: https://gist.github.com/bobthecow/19f09ebf4395ee9f87d9