# Single/double quotes in ng-init

Tags: php, angularjs, mustache, template-engine, mustache.php

Let's say we are passing initial data from php to Angular' view by Mustache, and the data is some string  that contain quotes, like *"Can't delete item"*.
Mustache by default translates the single quote to the `&#039;` like:

```
 ng-init="message='Can&#039;t delete item'"
```

but that causes some kind of Angular parsing problem:

> Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns ... ['] in expression [message='Can't delete item']

I can't use Mustache' triple curlies because then it will be like:

```
 ng-init="message='Can't delete item'"
```

with the same error in output.

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/GCq4gLrD1NxxCvAsjHy9?p=preview

How can we elegantly solve it on Mustache stage?

Comment: You should clarify your question's title. Can't you replace `&#039;` by `\'` and `&#34;` by `\"` before angular parsing?

Comment: I can't , it is coming "broken" from server

Comment: could not you initialise the value from your controller (or directive's link function)?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak no , it is a part of an old system (with a specific server/client relations scheme) that i can not change. what is Angular parsing mechanism' problem with a `&#039;` ?

Comment: @Cherniv did not go deep into it, but if you proceed `&#039` with \ then it seems to work fine: [http://plnkr.co/edit/HPmadiLEHBHs5l6XLKiV?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/HPmadiLEHBHs5l6XLKiV?p=preview)

Comment: @arturgrzesiak my Mustache runs on php , and it looks like: `ng-init="message='{{delete_message}}"` , so how am i able to put the `\\` there?

Comment: @Cherniv I do not use/know php: do you mean that `delete_message` cannot be set to: "Can\&#039;t delete item" in php or you are not able to change `delete_message` value at all?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak i cannot change `delete_message` value at all, and i'm sure that the problem is in angular because `'Can\&#039;t delete item'` seems to be a valid string , so i want to find a solution related to angular

Comment: @Cherniv The problem is that angular's lexer interprets unicode encoded characters. It seems to be an angular's bug. Check if this would work for you (order of double/single quotes changed): http://plnkr.co/edit/NaKdD4OquzBftxyls0B4?p=preview.

Answer (score 2):

I created a directive to place your content in, It will assign the body of directive to scope.message variable.

```
app.directive('myMessageVar',function(){
  return{
            restrict :'A',
            scope:{
              message:'=myMessageVar'
            },
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
               scope.message=iElement.text(); 
               iElement.text('');
          }
   }

})
```

In HTML

```
 <span my-message-var="message">Can&#039;t delete item</span>
```

Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QRtXLX1IiGS6VV0Rc78I?p=preview

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately i can't change the markup' structure

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the quote :

```
ng-init="message='Can\'t delete item'"
```

Comment: I can't do it because the html coming already broken from server

Answer (score 1):

Escape the single quote with the `backslash \` like this:

```
ng-init="message='Can\'t delete item'"
```

Comment: the same thing for esacping the double quotes

Comment: I can't do it because the html coming already broken from server

Comment: if you use php for getting data from server, please try  `htmlspecialchars_decode `

Comment: how can i combine it with Mustache?

Comment: See here for inspiration to integrate htmlspecialchars_decode() with Mustache: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195443/how-to-use-function-wrapper-in-mustache-php

Comment: @Werner you mean creating of some php helper function needed?

Comment: @Cherniv Yes, I'm talking about creating a Lambda, then you will have a solution tailored to your needs: https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/wiki/Mustache-Tags#lambdas

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the double quotes and the single quotes.

so instead of

```
ng-init="message='{{delete_message}}'"
```

try

```
ng-init='message="{{delete_message}}"'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this way if i will have double quote in my `delete_message` the error will appear again

Answer (score 1):

I came across with this problem today and I did not find much of an answer. But this piece of code works for me.

```
<?php $data_slashed = htmlentities(addslashes(html_entity_decode($data,ENT_QUOTES)),ENT_QUOTES); ?>
```

**Where `$data` is some data that were encoded using `htmlentities`**.

Then you can now do this

```
<p ng-bind-html= "data" ng-init="data='<?php echo $data_slashed; ?>'" />
```

I have not tried mustache but this works for my php template. Hope this help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using init incorrectly. From [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) docs:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

For passing values from your server-side I think you should either use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) (AJAX) or `Module.constant`/`Module.value` from [angular.Module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module).

For example:

```
// define a value
app.value('message','Can&#039;t delete item');

// define a constant
app.constant('constMessage', 'Can&#039;t delete item');
```

You can then inject them into services or controllers. e.g, for a controller:

```
// use it in a controller
app.controller('someController', ['$scope', 'message', 'constMessage', 
function($scope, message, constMessage) {
    $scope.message = message;
    $scope.constMessage = constMessage;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i know about `value` and `constant` and i'm using them in my another projects (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097923/angularjs-getting-data-inserted-in-dom/18097924), but in this specific project i able to use only the `ng-init` directive for passing data

Answer (score 0):

This may work if your problem is limited to single quotes

```
ng-init='message="Can&#039;t delete item"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  below code it should work.

`<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init='message="Can&#039;t delete item"'>
    <p>Message: {{message}}</p>
  </body>`